# How to achieve white toolbar with black title and black icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

i am trying to get toolbar like this one as show in image below [Note: instead of imageview on the left side there will be drawer icon]
[image: toolbar example]

but i am getting this as a result as shown in image below

[image: Resultant Toolbar]

i dont know why its adding black layer on the top of toolbar

this my toolbar code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and this is ToobarStyle code

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflowStyle</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButtonOverflowStyle">
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle"></style>
```

this are colors i used

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#b2b2b2</color>
```

what i can do **to achieve toolbar shown in first image**

Comment: try change the `android:colorPrimary` in the theme ?

Comment: Yes i have White as my primary color

Comment: i am not sure, but what if you remove all the theme attribute in the xml ?
can it change your background color ?

Comment: ohh thanks  i just removed background attribute and now its working . But Icons in toolbar still white what can i do for that i need black icons